# merge on two columns with two different tollerances, pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

my input:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A':['my ','fire','water','earth','monkey'],
        'B':[1,5,7,8,9],
        'C':[100,105,110,182,140]
                 })
print(df1)
        A  B    C
0     my   1  100
1    fire  5  105
2   water  7  110
3   earth  8  182
4  monkey  9  140

df2=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A':['drop','hold','push','pull','keep'],
        'B':[1,4,4,10,10],
        'C':[103,102,133,124,142]
                 })
print(df2)
      A   B    C
0  drop   1  103
1  hold   4  102
2  push   4  133
3  pull  10  124
4  keep  10  142
```

I want to merge those two df's (df1 & df2) using `pd.merge_asof()` or any other way

I can merge those two columns using one tollerance by :
`df= pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='B',direction='nearest',tolerance=2)`

**but I need to use two dirrefent tolerances for column B and C using: B_tol = 2,
C_tol = 4**

Expected output:

```
     A_x  B_x C_x   A_y  B_y    C_y  
0     my   1  100   drop   1    103 
1    fire  5  105   hold   4    102
2  monkey  9  140   keep  10    142
```

Expected output will  have only one col B and C when I will use merge on those cols, this output only shows an example how it should work

Comment: As peer the source code, I don't think it would be easily achievable,. You can subset data after your first merge to achieve what you need.

Comment: after first merge i will loose rows that i need for next merge. I am talking about rows with same values in one column

Comment: @jezrael hmm maybe we could you groupby for first tollerance, to create one column with something like gouper" to know which row in first tollerance should be compare, without changing anything. and then using groupby trying to create second columns with second tollerance. at the end we will have two new collumn and we can use them to merge rows, it make sense?

Comment: @jezrael please take a look on my answer proposition,  I have created combinations of dataframes with merge_asof and then i have used common part using index, give me your opinion please

Answer (score 0):

can we discuss this solution? i donw want to paste it to comments

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A':['my ','fire','water','earth','monkey'],
        'B':[1,5,7,8,9],
        'C':[100,105,110,182,140]
                 })

df2=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A':['drop','hold','push','pull','keep'],
        'B':[1,4,4,10,10],
        'C':[103,102,133,124,142]
                 })

df_1 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='B',direction='nearest',tolerance=2)
df_2 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='C'),df2.sort_values(by='C'),on='C',direction='nearest',tolerance=4)
df_3 = pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,on='B',direction='nearest',tolerance=2)
df_4 = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='C'),df1.sort_values(by='C'),on='C',direction='nearest',tolerance=4)
# df= pd.merge_asof(df3.sort_values(by='C_x'),df4.sort_values(by='C'),left_on='C_x',right_on='C',direction='nearest',tolerance=4).dropna()
df_12 = pd.merge(df_1,df_2,on='A_x').dropna()
df_34 = pd.merge(df_3,df_4,on='A_x').dropna()

print(df_12)
      A_x  B  C_x A_y_x    C_y  B_x    C A_y_y   B_y
0     my   1  100  drop  103.0    1  100  hold   4.0
1    fire  5  105  push  133.0    5  105  drop   1.0
4  monkey  9  140  pull  124.0    9  140  keep  10.0
print(df_34)
    A_x   B  C_x   A_y_x  C_y  B_x    C   A_y_y  B_y
0  drop   1  103     my   100    1  103    fire  5.0
1  hold   4  102    fire  105    4  102     my   1.0
4  keep  10  142  monkey  140   10  142  monkey  9.0
df = pd.merge(df_12,df_34,left_index=True,right_index=True)
print(df[['A_x_x','A_x_y']])
    A_x_x A_x_y
0     my   drop
1    fire  hold
4  monkey  keep
```